# Overlapping for AWS Subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am a little bit confused i defined in AWS an VPC with the CIDR 192.168.1.0/24 and based on this this subnets:

```
Subnet 1: 192.168.1.0/26 (64 Hosts)
Subnet 2: 192.168.1.64/28 (16 Hosts)
Subnet 3: 192.168.1.80/27 (32 Hosts)
```

and when I try to create this configuration I get the errors:

```
CIDR Address overlaps with existing Subnet CIDR: 192.168.1.64/28.
```

and

```
CIDR Address overlaps with existing Subnet CIDR: 192.168.1.81/27.
```

I start today with this topic and maybe there is something I don't know how to defined subnets in AWS, so I would very thanksful for a hint what I am doing wrong.
best regards
Dan

Comment: Note that `192.168.1.81/27` is a CIDR you didn't mention, did you check if there is a subnet with that CIDR you might have created when playing around earlier? Aside from that there are no conflicts in the three CIDR ranges you mentioned.

Comment: No the only other CIDR is the default and this use a complete other adressrange something what starts with 172.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening here is that your sub nets are spanning into each other and creating an overlap.

In other words, the 192.168.1.0 will span to 192.168.1.255

You may want to try increasing the 3rd octet by 1 for each new subnet.

Example: 192.168.1.0, 192.168.2.0 and so on.

Not too sure if this will fix your issue, but I figured I’d take a stab at it ha ha.

Check out this link to read a little more about the issue you’re most likely having.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to this party, but in case anyone else lands here:

This is happening because CIDRs are analogous to the older subnet masks, based on bit mapping, but are more a "line in the sand": the X in A.B.C.D/X is the number of most significant bits in the mask (set bits), with the remainder being 0. The start of the IP range is always set such that the IP A.B.C.D falls inside the range; A.B.C.D is *not necessarily* the start of the range.

Your CIDRs as masks are therefore:

```
11111111111111111111111111 000000 /26
1111111111111111111111111111 0000 /28
111111111111111111111111111 00000 /27
```

And applied to these IP addresses (in bits):

```
11000000101010000000000100 000000 192.168.1.0
1100000010101000000000010100 0000 192.168.1.64
110000001010100000000001010 10000 192.168.1.80
```

If we apply the masks (mask OR IP) we get these overlapping ranges:

```
11000000101010000000000100 000000 192.168.1.0  -> 192.168.1.63
1100000010101000000000010100 0000 192.168.1.64 -> 192.168.1.79
110000001010100000000001010 00000 192.168.1.64 -> 192.168.1.95
```

If we switch your ranges around a bit, however, these sizes can still work within the broader CIDR of your VPC:

```
192.168.1.0/26  = 192.168.1.0  -> 192.168.1.63
192.168.1.64/27 = 192.168.1.64 -> 192.168.1.95
192.168.1.96/28 = 192.168.1.96 -> 192.168.1.111
```

I'll leave testing the masks against the IP addresses in these CIDRs as an exercise for the reader!